# Performing a loop after another has finished

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, foreach

It's pretty simple really. I want the second loop to start only once the first on e has stopped...

```
            Dim i As Integer
        For Each c As Control In AllSongsPanel.Controls
            If c.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30) Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(c.Tag)
                i = c.Name
                c.Dispose()
                deletedCount = deletedCount + 1
            End If
        Next
        itemCount = 0
        For Each c As Control In AllSongsPanel.Controls
            If c.Width = AllSongsPanel.Width - 23 Then
                itemCount = itemCount + 1
                c.Name = itemCount
            End If
        Next
```

I don't really have many ideas on this and I can't find any questions on this on Google either. The ideas that I have will probably be more extensive than need be so I want to check if there's an easier solution first.
I've looked at For Loops on msdn and what not, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Well, it will work the way you wish, one instruction after the other... what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: Doesn't that happen anyway? I mean the first `For` loop will run, and then the second `For` will fire?

Comment: Whats the problem? are you having these two loops in seperate threads in actual code?

Comment: I dont think you want to dispose the controls in a loop looking at the controls.  The size of the list will change.  Flag the deleted ones and delete them in the second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the way you delete the controls.

```
Dim mDeleted as new List(of Control)
Dim i As Integer

For Each c As Control In AllSongsPanel.Controls
    If c.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(c.Tag)
        i = c.Name

        mDeleted.Add(c)

        ' no longer needed (?)
        'deletedCount = deletedCount + 1
    End If
Next

For each C as control in mDeleted
    ' i think this is the right syntax:
    AllSongsPanel.Controls.Remove(c)
Next

' add the second loop...not sure what it is doing
```

`deletedCount` is the same as `mDeleted.Count`.

`i As INTEGER = c.NAME` does not make much sense either.

Comment: I name the controls by their index in the control (AllSongsPanel). Don't worry about the deletedcontrols var; It's so I can change the maximum value of a custom trackbar, which I'm using as a scrolllbar

Comment: Just tried this and it isn't deleting all of the controls with the specified backcolour

Comment: Sorry, I was just being an idiot. I Have two controls that run mostly the same part and I was running the one that hadn't been edited. I'm gonna make a sub for each one to refer to now. All works now. (Before, it was missing out controls)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not threading anything off, this code is already synchronous.  You should be getting this behavior already.

Comment: I seems to do them both at the same time as not all the controls are disposed before their names are changed

Comment: @Josh-Mason it SEEMS that way because you are exiting the loop prematurely because you change the Controls array in the loop.  The more controls you delete, the more that are missed.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about what's actually happening, It's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete an item from a list while you are inside a for..each loop over this list. I'd first remember all items which shall be deleted and effectively delete them after. Something like this:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim deleteControls As New List(Of Control)
For Each c As Control In AllSongsPanel.Controls
    If c.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30) Then
        deleteControls.Add(c)
    End If
Next

For Each c As Control In deleteControls
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(c.Tag)
    i = c.Name
    AllSongsPanel.Controls.Remove(c)
    deletedCount = deletedCount + 1
Next
...
```

Comment: It works fine, apart from what the question is about so I don't think this will make any difference. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't running the code I edited, instead, I was running the old code:)